# What's the cost efficient way to create a mobile app for subscription based video streaming?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, video-streaming, digital-ocean

I started developing a mobile app using react native as frontend and Nodejs, MongoDB as backend. It is a subscription-based video streaming app, where users can subscribe to courses and view content whenever they want.

I am confused in deciding the following factors

1. Which cloud server is cost efficient to store and stream videos.
2. Does Digital ocean(less cost) support video transcoding like AWS?
3. If I go with Digital ocean, how videos are converted to suitable format and size based on user's device.
4. Is it possible to start this using any Dedicated server hosting from GoDaddy etc.,
5. Which framework I can use to play videos on the mobile app with controls(play, pause, forward)

Can someone please provide start to end flow how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be using video, your biggest issue will actually be the **cost of bandwidth**.

The lowest cost for Data Transfer on AWS is [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/), which ranges from 25c down to 2c per GB for high-volume commitments.

Please do your math on the amount of downloads your customers will use and you will probably find it very hard to justify the cost of bandwidth unless your users pay a substantial subscription fee. It will make the cost of servers unimportant by comparison.

Fortunately, most online subscription-based courses are rarely used (when compared to watching movies), so you might end up with many customers paying a subscription but using very little, which can improve the economics.

Or, just go with an existing platform like Udemy and **focus on the content** rather than the delivery method.